# Requiring scanf to recognise no input

Tags: c, newline, scanf

im very new to C programming, and i am looking for the simplest possible solution to getting scanf to recognise no input, by that i mean pressing the enter key with nothing typed and it knowing nothing has been entered and returning to the main menu. Iv looked about on here and i found a similar problem but scanf was taking an integer value, whereas i require a string for a filename. My code is:

```
    FILE *Fpacket;
    char filename[20];

    puts("Please declare a name for the file");   // request filename  
    scanf("%s", filename);    // store text in filename string
```

I have tried a combination of fgets, getchar and afew others but i just cant get it to take the newline character as input. I am aware scanf ignores preceding whitespace, any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: scanf will return the number of chars read, you can put a a=scanf(); and if(a==0) and that should work

Comment: @fernando.reyes thanks for your reply, but this code still doesent take the enter key as an input, it just goes onto the next line in the terminal

Comment: @user3043146 Suggest after some time (hours, days), amongst answers that meet your needs, accept the best one.  (Once you get to 15+ rep), up-vote all answers that are useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution using `%s` in `scanf("%s", filename)` as the format specifier consumes whitespace, including `\n` before attempting to fill `filename`. `scanf()` will not return until non-whitespace (or EOF or IO Error) occurs.

Much better to use `fgets()/sscanf()`

```
char buf[MAXPATH + 2];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) handle_EOF_IOError();
if (buf[0] == '\n')
  handle_OnlyEnterKeyPressed();
else 
  sscanf(buf, "%s", filename);
```

Comment: @Floris The `fgets()/sscanf()` idiom, though a bit awkward, is so much more robust than the problematic `scanf()`, I wounder why it is not taught straight out of the gate?  Like you, have similar tenure on Earth, I've eschewed `scanf()` completely.

Comment: it's a mystery to me too. Maybe C is considered a "starter" language, to be abandoned as soon as possible for a "real" language... so no need to learn anything practical - let's just confuse'em with pointers and move on. To Java? C#? Not sure what the "language of choice" is. I find the simplicity of C powerful.

Comment: @chux I have implemented this code into my program, when i call my save file function, it seems to jump to the bit where i handle the enter key being pressed without waiting for any input, could the "\n" value still be in the input buffer from my menu select?

Comment: @user3043146 I suspect you have a `scanf()` in preceding code.  That `scanf()` likely left the preceding <Enter> in `stdin`.  Best to not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  Use one or the other throughout code.  Recommend to avoid `scanf()`.  Another idea follows...

Comment: @user3043146 A common idiom is to consume _all_ user input before prompting for new input.  This approach is problematic for learners. So I'm backing off on presenting it. - Sorry.  Instead, easiest to use `fgets(buf, , stdin)` for _all_ _user_ input and `sscanf(buf, ...)`.

Comment: Ah yes my menu switch function takes its value from a scanf

Answer (score -1):

If you want to take a Newline(Enter) character from the keyboard as input, then you need to use another key to terminate the string
//press Esc to terminate the string.

```
int main() {
char filename[20];
char ch;
int i;
i=0;
while ((filename[i] = std::cin.get()) != 27 && i<20) {
i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

If you press enter on your keyboard, it will take it as character and store it on filename[i], the while loop will never terminate until you press Esc or i<20

Comment: Why are you using iostreams when the question is about C?

Comment: @SantanuXCowBoy This is a question about C - notice the C tag at the bottom of the question.  Your post, using `std::cin.get()` requires another language (C++).  Good luck on future posts.